# Verb form of the word 'sic'

Tags: verbs

I was wondering if there was a verb form for the word 'sic'.

Eg: "Hey, you could've quoted me when you gave that speech."

Or

"Hey, you could've sicced me when you gave that speech."

However according to Google, 'sicced' means to pursue someone.

Answer (score 2):

The word *sic* does not mean "to quote" in the general sense you suggest. It specifically means that something is written as it is deliberately, often because it is copied exactly including any [apparent] errors.

> sic (adverb): intentionally so written — used after a printed word or passage to indicate that it is intended exactly as printed or to indicate that it exactly reproduces an original

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sic)

The verb sic/sick is a completely different word. It is a dialect version of "seek".

Answer (score 1):

"Sic" is not a word of general English. It is a Latin word and it is used to talk *about* a quoted text.  It is almost exclusively used in writing, and then only in fairly formal texts.

For example, in a pupil's school report:

> Mary's spelling is very poor. In her last essay she wrote "When a soled[sic] luzes[sic] its form". She should be assessed for dyslexia.

The writer has added editorial comments in square brackets. "Sic" means "thus" or "yes" in Latin. The editorial comments mean that "this is the actual spelling used in the original."

*sic* is not part of speech. It is not a noun, verb or any other part of English speech, and you don't form "sicced".

Comment: *Sic* most certainly is an English [verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sic), and one from which *sicced* can be formed. What you mean to say is that there is no verb equivalent of the *adverb* "sic."